# Find the value of x for which the annual produce takes the lager value

Tags: functions

There are 20 plants that produce 60 kg fruits each in a year. With the raise of the number of plants the production decreases. This decrease is 2kg in a year for each plant (over the number 20). for which value of x, this fruit production takes the biggest value?

Firstly I said that y=(20+x)60-2x is the tree production annual. How should I proceed?

Comment: General method: A. Compute $y'(x)$ and find the values of $x$ for which $y'(x)=0$. B. Compute $y''(x)$ and check for which of the values you found, $y''(x)<0$. C. Put those values in the original $y(x)$ and pick the one which yields the greatest result.

Comment: could you be more clear? Should I put (20+x)60-2x=0 firstly and take x=-20,69 and then (20+x)60-2x<0 and take x<-20,69 and then?

Comment: Forget it. Your function seems to be monotonically increasing. So assuming you've computed it correctly (I have not verified that in your question), you can simply input the largest possible value of $x$.

Comment: Which is? How can I find it? That' all this question is about.

Comment: What does $x$ represent in that formula you wrote there?

Comment: the number of plants over the number of 20 so the 21th, 22th plant, etc(it was an instruction of the problem)

Comment: And what is the maximum number of plants that you can have?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the values for $x=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.  Which value gives the biggest crop?
I think each tree loses 2x, so the total crop will be $(20+x)(60-2x)$ rather than $(20+x)60-2x$.

Comment: where did you get 25? And it says that when the number of the trees  up the number 20.

Comment: Whoops, corrected now.